# Grok Filter String Pattern

Tags: logstash-grok, graylog2

I am pretty new to Grok and I need to filter a line as the one below:

`Dec 20 18:46:00 server-04 script_program.sh[14086]: 2017-12-20 18:46:00 068611 +0100 - server-04.location-2 - 14086/0x00007f093b7fe700 - processname/SIMServer - 00000000173d9b6b - info - work: You have 2 connections running`

So far I just managed to get the following:

`SYSLOGBASE %{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp} (?:%{SYSLOGFACILITY} )?%{SYSLOGHOST:logsource} %{SYSLOGPROG}:`

So I get all the date/timestamp details + program + process which is ok.

But that leaves me with the following remaining string:

`2017-12-20 18:46:00 068611 +0100 - server-04.location-2 - 14086/0x00007f093b7fe700 - processname/SIMServer - 00000000173d9b6b - info - work: You have 2 connections running`

And here I am struggling to break everything into chunks.

I have tried lot of combinations trying to split that based on the hyphen (-) but I am failing so far to do so..

So far I have been pretty much using as a guideline the following:

https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns

Any help/suggestions/tips on this please?
I am using graylog2 and as shown above, trying to use GROK for filtering my messages out..

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get my filter fully done and working. so the solution is below:

```
SERVER_TIMESTAMP_ISO8601 %{YEAR}-%{MONTHNUM}-%{MONTHDAY}[T ]%{HOUR}:?%
{MINUTE}(?::?%{SECOND})?[T ]%{INT}[T ]%{ISO8601_TIMEZONE}?
SERVER_HOSTNAME \b(?:[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-]{0,62})(?:\.(?:[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-]{0,62}))*(\.?|\b)
SERVER_Unknown  %{SERVER_HOSTNAME}[/]%{SERVER_HOSTNAME}
SERVER_Loglevel ([Aa]lert|ALERT|[Tt]race|TRACE|[Dd]ebug|DEBUG|[Nn]otice|NOTICE|[Ii]nfo|INFO|[Ww]arn?(?:ing)?|WARN?(?:ING)?|[Ee]rr?(?:or)?|ERR?(?:OR)?|[Cc]rit?(?:ical)?|CRIT?(?:ICAL)?|[Ff]atal|FATAL|[Ss]evere|SEVERE|EMERG(?:ENCY)?|[Ee]merg(?:ency)?)

SYSLOGBASE_SERVER %{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp} (?:%{SYSLOGFACILITY} )?%{SYSLOGHOST:logsource} %{SYSLOGPROG}:[T ]%{SERVER_TIMESTAMP_ISO8601: timestamp_match}[T ]-[T ]%{SERVER_HOSTNAME:SERVER_host_node}[T ]-[T ]%{SERVER_Unknown:SERVER_Unknown}[T ]-[T ]%{SERVER_Unknown:service_component}[T ]-[T ]%{SERVER_HOSTNAME:process_code_id}[T ]-[T ]%{SERVER_Loglevel}[T ]-[T ]%{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}
```

All the rest or regular expresions from GROK.

Many thanks